# Google Apps Script trigger to create Google Calendar events is failing

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

My Google Apps Script works with the "On edit" trigger with no issues.
However, when I try to put a time based daily trigger it gets a 100% error rate.
Can someone help me understand why this may be happening? The App Script code is below.

```
function schedule_shifts() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var calendarId = spreadsheet.getRange("D1").getValue();
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  var signups = spreadsheet.getRange("A3:C19").getValues();
for (x=0; x<signups.length; x++) {
   var shift = signups[x]
   var startTime = shift[0];
   var endTime = shift[1];
   var name = shift[2];
   eventCal.createEvent(name, startTime, endTime)
 }
}
```

'''

Comment: Script is failing is not a question

Answer (score 0):

#### Try it this way

```
function schedule_shifts() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var calendarId = spreadsheet.getRange("D1").getValue();
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  var signups = spreadsheet.getRange("A3:C19").getValues();
for (x=0; x<signups.length; x++) {
   var shift = signups[x]
   var startTime = new Date(shift[0]);
   var endTime = new Date(shift[1]);
   var name = shift[2];
   eventCal.createEvent(name, startTime, endTime)
 }
}
```

Be more specific about what is wrong